# datetimepicker - убрать выбор прошедшего времени

Tags: php, javascript

Есть календарь, настроенный через

```
$('.calendar').datetimepicker({
    theme: 'dark',
    minDate: new Date('<?=time()?>'),
    onSelectTime: onSelectTime
});
```

Дата работает верно, то есть - та дата которая уже была, выбрать нельзя.
Но с временем проблема, то время которое уже было можно выбирать, а так не надо.
И вообще проблема в том, что время идет без минут, а только круглые часы.

```
00:00 - 23:00
```

Пробовал менять параметр format на: H:i и другие, не срабатывает.
Нужно вообще, чтобы так же, как дата следовало, в том же порядке, без выбора прошедшего времени. Спасайте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex вопрос остаётся, как убрать/заменить время если оно меньше текущего,в примере выбрать завтрашний день, затем время меньше текущего,после выбрать выбрать текущую дату, результат выбрать время нельзя, но в инпуте время из прошлого выбора ... похоже недоработка плагина, или смену minTime нужно добавить в другое место

```js
$(function() {
  $(".calendar").datetimepicker({
    minTime: new Date,
    format: "d.m.Y H:m",
    minDate: new Date,
    onSelectDate: function(ct, $i) {
      this.setOptions({
        minTime: ct.getTime() > new Date ? false : 0
      })
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="calendar" />
```

Comment: а что вам мешает в onSelectDate при выборе текущей даты сразу записать текущую дату и текущее время прямо в инпут

Comment: @Alex не могли бы вы показать код

Comment: добавил пример в свой ответ

Comment: Так и сделал, только дату беру с сервера и дни тоже и нужно было, чтобы если уже 23 и еще нет 00:00, чтобы 23 можно еще было выбирать и так со всеми, условие >=. Все норм, задача решена. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

По минимальной дате использовал их конструкцию:

```
minDate: 0, //today
```

по времени - можно установить разрешенное время (если программно, то можно указать любой интервал)

```
{allowTimes:[
  '09:00',
  '11:00',
  '12:00',
  '15:30',
  '21:00'
]}
```

Дальше можно прикрутить установку минимального времени в зависимости от выбранной даты на событие

```
    onSelectDate:function(ct,$i){
      minTimesNew = ....
      $('.calendar').datetimepicker('setOptions', {minTime:minTimesNew });
    }
```

здесь проверять, если сегодня, то установить минимальное значения времени - текущее ({minTime:0}// now), иначе все {minTime:'00:00'}

Пример. При выборе текущей даты устанавливается по умолчанию следующий час:

```
$(function() {
  $(".calendar").datetimepicker({
    minTime: 0,
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
    minDate:'-1970/01/01', // today is minimum date
    onSelectDate: function(ct, $i) {
    var minTime, now = new Date;
    if(ct.getTime() > now){
        minTime = false;
    }else{
        var d = $i.val().substr(0, 11) + (Number(now.getHours()) + 1).toString() + ':00';
        $i.val(d);
        minTime = 0;
    }
      this.setOptions({
        minTime: minTime
      })
    }
  })
});
```